# Customizer: active_callback and sanitize_callback incompatibility?

Tags: php, theme-development, customization, themes, theme-customizer

Below are a few Customizer controls I have for my site logo - Display Logo, Logo File and Logo Size. As you can see, I'm using an `active_callback` so that when the `display_logo` checkbox is unchecked, it not only removes the logo from the front end but also hides the other two settings from the Customizer (until the checkbox is checked again).

It works fine except when I try to sanitize the `display_logo` checkbox, at which point unchecking the checkbox neither hides the logo on the front end nor the other two settings from the Customizer.

```
// Display Logo
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'display_logo', array(
    'default'           => true,
    'sanitize_callback' => 'my_theme_sanitize_checkbox',    
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'display_logo', array(
    'label'             => __( 'Logo', 'my-theme' ),
    'type'              => 'checkbox',
    'section'           => 'title_tagline', 
) );
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'display_logo', array(
    'selector'          => '.site-logo'
) );
function display_logo_callback( $control ) {
    if ( $control->manager->get_setting( 'display_logo' )->value() == true ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Logo File
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'site_logo', array(
    'default'           => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/logo.jpg',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'my_theme_sanitize_file'
) );    
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'site_logo', array(
    'label'             => __( 'Logo File', 'my-theme' ),
    'flex_width'        => true, 
    'flex_height'       => true,
    'width'             => 100,
    'height'            => 100,
    'settings'          => 'site_logo',
    'section'           => 'title_tagline',
    'active_callback'   => 'display_logo_callback'
) ) );

// Logo Size
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'site_logo_size' , array(
    'default'           => '3',
    'transport'         => 'postMessage',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'my_theme_sanitize_number_range'
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'site_logo_size', array(
    'label'             => __( 'Logo Size', 'my-theme' ),
    'type'              => 'range',
    'input_attrs'       => array(
        'min'           => 0,
        'max'           => 10,
        'step'          => 0.001
    ),
    'section'           => 'title_tagline',
    'active_callback'   => 'display_logo_callback',
) );

// Sanitize Checkbox
function my_theme_sanitize_checkbox( $input ) {
    return ( isset( $input ) ? true : false );
}

// Sanitize File
function my_theme_sanitize_file( $file, $setting ) {
    $mimes = array(
        'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif'          => 'image/gif',
        'png'          => 'image/png'
    );
    $file_ext = wp_check_filetype( $file, $mimes );
    return ( $file_ext['ext'] ? $file : $setting->default );
}

// Sanitize Number Range
function my_theme_sanitize_number_range( $number, $setting ) {
    $number = absint( $number );
    $atts = $setting->manager->get_control( $setting->id )->input_attrs;
    $min = ( isset( $atts['min'] ) ? $atts['min'] : $number );
    $max = ( isset( $atts['max'] ) ? $atts['max'] : $number );
    $step = ( isset( $atts['step'] ) ? $atts['step'] : 0.001 );
    return ( $min <= $number && $number <= $max && is_int( $number / $step ) ? $number : $setting->default );
}
```

Comment: the argument received by `my_theme_sanitize_checkbox` is `TRUE` or `FALSE` then to sanitize the value, you should try `return (bool) $input;`.

Comment: @mmm if you can write out how it should be and it works, I can accept it as the answer. Thanks!